# note plays infinitely on long key press while using audioContext javascript

Tags: javascript

i am implementing a simple piano using audioContext. The notes are played normally in short time press but when a key is pressed continuously for a long time then the sound plays infinately.please help thank you

```
function Main() {
    // Create audio (context) container
    var audioCtx = new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)();
    var pressed;
    var osc;
    var key;
    // Table of notes with correspending keyboard codes. Frequencies are in hertz.
    var notesByKeyCode = {
        65: { noteName: 'c4', frequency: 261.6, keyName: 'a' },
        83: { noteName: 'd4', frequency: 293.7, keyName: 's' },
        68: { noteName: 'e4', frequency: 329.6, keyName: 'd' },
        70: { noteName: 'f4', frequency: 349.2, keyName: 'f' },
        71: { noteName: 'g4', frequency: 392, keyName: 'g' },
        72: { noteName: 'a4', frequency: 440, keyName: 'h' },
        74: { noteName: 'b4', frequency: 493.9, keyName: 'j' },
        75: { noteName: 'c5', frequency: 523.3, keyName: 'k' },
        76: { noteName: 'd5', frequency: 587.3, keyName: 'l' },
        186: { noteName: 'e5', frequency: 659.3, keyName: ';' }
    };



     function Key(noteName, keyName, frequency) {
            console.log(frequency);
            var keySound = new Sound(frequency);
            return keySound;
        }

        function Sound(frequency) {
            osc = audioCtx.createOscillator(); // Create oscillator node
            pressed = false; // flag to indicate if sound is playing
            osc.frequency.value = frequency;
            osc.type = 'triangle';
            osc.start(0);
        };

        Sound.prototype.play = function() {
            if(!pressed) {
                pressed = true;
                osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                console.log('play');
            }
        };

        Sound.prototype.stop = function() {
            osc.disconnect();
            pressed = false;

            console.log('stop');

        };


        var playNote = function(event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            key = new Sound(notesByKeyCode[keyCode].frequency);
            console.log(notesByKeyCode[keyCode].frequency);
            key.play();
        };

        var endNote = function(event) {
            console.log(pressed,'endnote');
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            key.stop();
        };

        window.addEventListener('keydown', playNote);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', endNote);

    }

    Main();
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not for taking orders for code snippets. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Are you generating the tone or are you playing a sound file?

Comment: sorry...i have added my code. i am generating the tone

Answer (score 0):

If you still interested in an answer. i guess i can try to explain this behavior.

If you call "console.log" in playNote function, you will see the function executes many times if you keep the key pressed. I don't know why the endNote function doesn't stop the sound ( maybe "key" doesn't remove the previous reference of "Sound" ).

As a quick solution, i modified the code:

```
var playNote = function(event) {
    console.log("Function xD")
    if(!pressed) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        key = new Sound(notesByKeyCode[keyCode].frequency);
        console.log(notesByKeyCode[keyCode].frequency);
        key.play();
    }
};
```

Since the function "playNote" is called many times, i just copy your condition in "Sound.prototype.play" so to avoid recreate the variable "key".

this work at least in Chrome 47.